# Take info from array and write it in div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

This is my JavaScript

```js
// info array
let myArray = [
 { hat: 'polo',
   shirt: 'buttonup',
   shoe: 'nike'
 },
 { 
   hat:  'top',
   shirt: 'pullover',
   shoe: 'addias'
 }, 
 {  
   hat: 'baseball',
   shirt: 'tshirt',
   shoe: 'flipflop'
 }, 
]

// printToDom function
const printToDom = (divId, textToPrint) => {
 const selectedDiv = document.getElementById(divId);
 selectedDiv.innerHTML = textToPrint
 };

// studentPrinter function (writes to div)
 const studentPrinter = (myArray) => {
   let domString = '';
   for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
     domString += `<div class="col-2">${myArray[i].hat}</div>`
     domString += `<div class="col-3">${myArray[i].shirt}</div>`
     domString += `<div class="col-3">${myArray[i].shirt}</div>`
     }
     printToDom('allInfo', domstring)

// init function (starts studentPrinter)
Const init = () => {
 studentPrinter(myArray);
 };
init ();
```

This is my HTML

```html
<div id="allInfo"></div>
```

What I want to do is use the `init()` function to start the `studentPrinter` function, passing `myArray` which contains information about the student.  It should print out all of the information of the student into the `div` in my HTML, but for some reason, it does not.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your `studentPrinter` function has a typo. `array1.length` should be `myArray.length`.

Comment: In your code the for loop is iterating over `array1`, but the parameter passed to your arrow function is called `myArray`. This could likely be the source of your bug.

Comment: Hi Mate, enjoy your learning! :)
Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/6973Lmbw/ you can use jsfiddle to help share your code as well.

Comment: The preferred way of sharing HTML/CSS/JS code on Stack Overflow is [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar). It has much of the same functionality as jsfiddle. cc: @JoséCoelho.

Answer (score 1):

Check for the array name in the for loop , condition should be on `myArray` and not `array1`

```js
const studentPrinter = (myArray) => {
    let domString = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      domString += `<div class="col-2">${myArray[i].hat}</div>`
      domString += `<div class="col-3">${myArray[i].shirt}</div>`
      domString += `<div class="col-3">${myArray[i].shirt}</div>`
      }
      printToDom('allInfo', domstring)
```

Also, since you are new to Javascript I would recommend that you look for the use of **debugger** and **console.log()** statements for finding bugs in the code.